# Get all tags not just first 10 with wp api 2.0

Tags: database, tags, api, wp-api, rest-api

if I do `/wp-json/wp/v2/tags` I only can get first 10, and seems the adding `per_page=0` no longer work on it for getting actually all tags.

Anyone knows how to actually get all the tags with [wp-api 2.0](http://v2.wp-api.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the `WP_REST_Controller::get_collection_params()` method, we can see the *minimum* is `1` and the *maximum* is `100`:

```
'per_page' => array(
    'description'        => __( 'Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.' ),
    'type'               => 'integer',
    'default'            => 10,
    'minimum'            => 1,
    'maximum'            => 100,
    'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
    'validate_callback'  => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
),
```

If we check the `CHANGELOG.md`file  we find this:

> ```
> - Enforces minimum 1 and maximum 100 values for `per_page` parameter.
>
> (props @danielbachhuber,
> [#2209](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/pull/2209))
> ```

There we see that this is related to issue [#1609](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1609) where @rmccue [comment](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1609#issuecomment-184027871) is:

> You should be able to filter `rest_endpoints` and change the maximum
>   value there. This should potentially be easier, but ideally you
>   shouldn't be changing this.

The [`rest_endpoints`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_endpoints/) filter is applied within the `WP_REST_Server::get_routes()` method:

```
/**
 * Filters the array of available endpoints.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array $endpoints The available endpoints. An array of matching regex patterns,
 *                         each mapped to an array of callbacks for the endpoint. 
 *                         These take the format
 *                         `'/path/regex' => array( $callback, $bitmask )` or
 *                         `'/path/regex' => array( array( $callback, $bitmask ).
 */
 $endpoints = apply_filters( 'rest_endpoints', $this->endpoints );
```

As an example we could try:

```
/**
 * Change the maximum of per_page for /wp/v2/tags/ from 100 to 120
 */
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints )
{
    if( isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/tags'][0]['args']['per_page']['maximum'] ) )
        $endpoints['/wp/v2/tags'][0]['args']['per_page']['maximum'] = 120;

    return $endpoints;  
} );
```

Another approach could be through the  `rest_post_tag_query` filter:

```
/**
 * Fix the per_page to 120 for the post tags query of get_terms()
 */
add_filter( 'rest_post_tag_query', function( $args, $request )
{
    $args['number'] = 120;
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where you might want to adjust this further to your needs.

Note that this default restriction on `per_page` could "protect" your server, from hight load, if your install has large number of terms.